# Does autocompletion/changing directories in bash necessarily go through CDPATH?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I can `cd Documents` from anywhere on my file system, and I land in `~/Documents`.
In fact `cd Doc` followd by TAB and Enter gets me there.
Now I checked my CDPATH and it doesn't include `~/Documents`.
Typing `echo $CDPATH` in a terminal outputs only my home directory.
So where does bash get this information from?
My goal is to add some folders deep into my file system to my CDPATH.

My `.bashrc` contains only `export CDPATH=~`, and there is no `.bash_profile` in my home directory.

Comment: That is precisely how `cd` operates when `CDPATH` is set. Try directories other than `Documents` and you will witness the same behavior.

Comment: @oguz ismail Thanks! Now suppose I have a subdirectory `~/Documents/dir1` and I want to cd to `dir1` from any where in my file system, how can I do that? I tried to include the path to `dir1` into `.bashrc` using `export ~/Documents/dir1`, but it didn't work.
My goal is to add some folders deep into my file system to my `CDPATH`.

Comment: you need to add `~/Documents` to `CDPATH` then.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything is working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CDPATH` is an environment variable. It looks exactly like the PATH variable containing with many different paths concatenated using ':'.

For example if you run:

```sh
$ cat file.txt
```

This actually is running:

```sh
$ /usr/bin/cat file.txt
```

This is what `$PATH` is helpful for.

The `$CDPATH` is similar it will look into your locations that you set (by order), and will give you a suggestion to change your directory.

For example if you want to go to a directory in /var/lib wherever you are, you can set this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
export CDPATH=".:/home/mahdy:/var/lib"
```

**REMEMBER:** If `$CDPATH` is set, the `cd` command won't check your current directory first, so you'll need to add that `.` first then prioritize the rest of your paths.

This means, this syntax **is not standard**:

```sh
export CDPATH="~"
```

**Correct syntax:**

```sh
export CDPATH=".:~"
```

Comment: I had a specific problem to which @oguz ismail kindly replied. Having said that your answer was so clear that I accepted it a solution, thank you!